# Problem with index server talking to remote server names with dashes or dots in them

Tags: indexing, indexing-service

Hi I am having a problem, accessing a remote index server catalog. The name of the server has - in it, so i put the index catalog name as:

i.e num.num.num.num\name of catalog
or  an-example-server

I get the following error when using an ole data connection to pull results from the index:

"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 39"

I tried putting single quotes and &qoute; with no luck - anyone have idea?

PS. This Microsoft Index Server Question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer or certainly a solution. By adding an A record on the domain (with a friendly name), I managed to talk to the remote catalog without any problems. :)